# Is there a common API, to remotely execute Ubuntu shell commands?

Tags: networking

I know I can use ncat -l -e /bin/bash and then configure the firewall to only allow a connection from me.  However, I'm interested to consider any other common API to do remote Ubuntu shell commands.

Comment: Ehmmm... Excuse me if I am wrong but... Doesn't SSH work for you in this case? Maybe I am misunderstanding the question. Sorry if so.

Comment: ssh is the go to and is more secure . You can use web interfaces as well (webmin and similar)

Comment: Yes, ssh with port forwarding, will let me simply open a local socket to perform the remote activities.  Thx!!!